# PHP: Wrap iframe in div only once

Tags: php, html, iframe, str-replace

I just noticed that a part of my code that handles posting of user stories does not function the way it should.

Whenever a user has an iframe in his post (example YouTube embedded video) my PHP script wraps the iframes in a div like this `<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">`.

The code I use for this is simple:

```
$content = str_replace(['<iframe', '</iframe>'], ['<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9"><iframe', '</iframe></div>'], $content);
```

The problem is that when changes are made to this post, the same PHP code is being executed in the background with ajax and the iframe is wrapped again in this div, which gives something like this

```
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
    <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
        <iframe ...></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have been thinking about this a lot and the solution is probably very easy, but how can I check with PHP if the iframe is already wrapped in my div with `embed-responsive` class?

Comment: check if the content begins with `<div>`. If it doesn't, add the wrapper.

Comment: But $content is the entire post content, so there are tags and text before and after the iframe. How can I test if there is a div in front of an iframe in that string?

Comment: check against a regex like this: /<div class=".*embed-responsive.*>\s*<iframe/

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to detect if the frames are already wrapped if you normalize the existing iframes in `$content` with:

```
    $content = str_replace(['<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9"><iframe', '</iframe></div>'], ['<iframe', '</iframe>'], $content);
```

All iframes in `$content` will have their `div` parts removed now. Now execute the `str_replace` you already have in place to wrap the iframes again:

```
    $content = str_replace(['<iframe', '</iframe>'], ['<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9"><iframe', '</iframe></div>'], $content);
```

The `div`parts have been added to the frames again and you will end up with all iframes being wrapped only once.

Answer (score 1):

you may have to check if the iframe has a parent already. this could be done by added a class when you replace the first time then use that as a conditional in your replace

```
if(strpos($content,'class="i-wrapped" ')!== false ){
    //the iframe has not been wrapped
    $content = str_replace(
        ['<iframe', '</iframe>'], 
        ['<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">'.
         '<iframe class="i-wrapped"', '</iframe></div>'],
        $content);
}else { /*already wrapped*/}
```

now some caveats with a solution like this it will only account for a single iFrame if you had more than one in a post this solution would **fail**.

another option may be to count the number of occurances of iframes and then perform the replace(s) that way